# $m_*(E_1\cup E_2)=m_*(E_1)+ m_*(E_2)$ with this condition?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $G_1,G_2\subseteq\mathbb R^d $ be two disjoint open sets. Then for any $E_1\subseteq G_1,E_2\subseteq G_2,$ show that $m_*(E_1\cup E_2)=m_*(E_1)+ m_*(E_2).$ "$m_*$" here is exterior measure. It is clear to see that $m_*(E_1\cup E_2)\leq m_*(E_1)+ m_*(E_2).$ But how to prove that $m_*(E_1\cup E_2)\geq m_*(E_1)+ m_*(E_2)?$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon >0$. There is an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $E_1\cup E_2$ s.t. $$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty |U_i|\leq  m^*(E_1\cup E_2)+\varepsilon.\tag{1}$$

Notice that $\{G_1\cap U_i\}$ and $\{G_2\cap U_i\}$ is an open cover of $E_1$ and $E_2$ respectively, and both are disjoint. Therefore
\begin{align*}
m^*(E_1)+m^*(E_2)&\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty |U_i\cap G_1|+\sum_{i=1}^\infty |U_i\cap G_2|\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty |U_i\cap (G_1\cup G_2)|\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty |U_i|.\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Combines $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields $$m^*(E_1)+m^*(E_2)\leq m^*(E_1\cup E_2)+\varepsilon .$$
Since $\varepsilon >0$ is unspecified, we obtain the wished result.

Comment: Can open cover be replaced by closed cover?

Comment: well, you can define the exterior measure $\nu^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{j}|F_i|\mid E\subset \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty F_i,\text{ $F_i$ closed}\right\},$ and indeed, $\nu^*(E)=m^*(E)$ for all $E\subset \mathbb R$.